# How can I convert my input String to an integer with a base conversion

Tags: java, base-conversion

I want my code whenever I input a base from 2-36 , It can output a number which is decimal. here is my code

```
package code;

public class solution{
    public static int x2ten(String s, int base){

        String[] bits = s.split("");
        int result = 0;


        for(int i=0; i < bits.length; i++ ){




            int val = (Integer.parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i])) * ((int)Math.pow(base,i));
                val = charToInt(Integer.parseInt(bits[bits.length-1-i]))* ((int)Math.pow(base,i));



            result += val;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int charToInt(char c){
        char[] characters = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G',
                'H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

        for(int j = 0; j<characters.length; j++){
            if(characters[j] == c){
                return j;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }





    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
             System.out.println(x2ten("1101",2));
    }
}
```

There is a problem at first appear charToInt, it said that I should change charToInt(char c) to charToInt(int c). But whats purpose of charToInt is convert whatever I input a Character like 1A, then it can output 26 in decimal.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "outputting 26 in decimal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wheel that's [already been invented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)):

```
public static int x2ten(String s, int base) {
    return Integer.parseInt(s, base);
}
```

I would advise deleting your method entirely in favour of the one from the JDK, which even has the same signature.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using your own code, you should maybe take in mind following things:

1. If you want to get an array for all characters in a string, use the `toCharArray()` method. This gives you a `char[]`, which will also be more useful in the rest of your program
2. What's the point of assigning a value to `val` if you never use that value and immediately get another value in there. Get rid of that first line. It doesn't seem to be very useful, does it?
3. Be careful with `Integer.parseInt(String s)` if you use literals in your numbers. It should throw a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can notice that in the **function call** to the function **charToInt()**, you are passing an **integer** as an argument but if you see the **definition** of your function, it is expecting a character.Hence it is suggesting you to change it to **int**. Hope this helps :)